# Editing IP source range in GCP

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, server, ip, firewall

I understand that 0.0.0.0/0 this means that i'm allowed whatever my IP is to connect to this instance(server).

I'm trying to modify my **GCP instance firewall rule**, to allow my IP only to access this instance, I'm accessing it via **ssh** as it's an **ubuntu server**. So I've to specify in the rule some adress in the form of 0.0.0.0/0 where my **public IP** is not in this format.

I don't understand the following

- what is /0 means ?
- How to generate an IP that match this format ?
- Should I be using my public IP or another kind of IP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired to provide my IP4/32 it still wasn't working. But i found a solution for this problem.

**solution**

First go to [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding)
Copy this IP `35.235.240.0/20` under Preparing your project for IAP TCP forwarding

> This range contains all IP addresses that IAP uses for TCP forwarding

- Paste the copied IP inside the `IP source` of your firewall rule.
- Go to [What_Is_My_IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) and copy your IPv4
- Add your copied IP to the `IP source range` inside your firewall rule
- save, and start your ssh connection to the VM

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Wiki Article on CIDR notation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation

In GCP (and possibly elsewhere), the CIDR range of `0.0.0.0/0` is used to donate any address at all.

If you want to restrict traffic to your Compute Engine instance at the IP level, then:

1. Determine your own IP address ... for example `1.2.3.4`
2. Change the firewall rule to allow only traffic from `1.2.3.4/32`

Given that an IP address (ipV4) is 32 bits then when we suffix a CIDR range with `/32` we are saying *the whole IP address must match*.

Comment: Thank you.  But I've tried to include my IP4/32 in the IP sources and connect but it still preventing me from using it. i think i'm providing it wrongly.

Comment: The community will be happy to assist.  I'm still pretty comfortable that the recipe is still valid.  Maybe post the question on the slack channel at #networking on the community googlecloud-community.slack.com and we can have a live chat.

Answer (score 0):

1) Get the external ip from where you going to ssh with typing ( what is my ip ) in any  browser , copy that ip

2) create firewall rule and use that external ip e.g 35.34.36.37/32 for port 22 (ssh ) with "apply to all instance" option set

3) If you are using putty for ssh then make sure to export the ssh key to the instance 
After following all above step if should work

Comment: That's what i've done i went what is my IP, and used it in the default firewall for the ssh instance and add (myIP/32) then saved, when i tried to connect it still prevents me as it's not seeing my IP.

Comment: We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best recommendation I would give is to open a case on issuetracker where your project will inspect closely by GCP team if you dont have any support package orthherwise open a case directly from your project.

The reason behind this recommendation is because some needs to inspect your project for solving your problem

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've found a solution for the problem.

Comment: I've updated the question with the solution please check it.